# How RedirectToAction determines when site is consumed from Internet?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I've been working on a Web site with ASP.NET MVC version 1, deployed in a Windows Server 2008 R2 (IIS7, integrated mode).  The site works well in intranet enviroment, but recently was published in Internet with a public domain name.  RedirectToAction still aims to private IP, causing redirect to login page.  Where I can specify the change?

For notAnExpert petition, an extract of my code.  Nothing special here, only the default conventions:

```
return RedirectToAction(string.Format("Details/{0}", CampaignId), "Campaigns");
```

In my Global.asax neither:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("clicked_links", "Clicked/Index", new { controller="Clicked", action="Index"});


        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

Comment: Could you post code on how RedirectToAction  looks like. Alternatively you may want to look at your RouteHandler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault guys, in the view I find this

```
 <form action=<% Request.URL %>
```

Additionaly the web server was misconfigured.